# How to find an API of a Web Application? Without any tools

Tags: api, interface

I'm working on problem with an application on our server. The application has a web-interface where I can enter username, pw, date, path, identifier and expected output format - csv in general. The requested data will be downloaded to the directory.

This application was designed a few years ago by a firm that is no longer existing. The documentation is nearly 100% lost and we don't know the source code. All we know is, that there is an API to do the same as I can do manually.

Due to company restrictions I'm not able to scan with postman or jmeter to find the API. Is there a way to find how to send my request from a program with the same result?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem with a bit of Unix Shell. I have searched for all directories on the webserver where the app is running. In a subfolder I found the XML declaration of API.

```
wget --spider -r --no-parent http://hostname:port/
ls -l hostname:port
```

Hope this will help someone else.